# Class instatiation using pointers

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

Could someone shed some light on how the next piece of code works on the creation of the object ***b***?? It looks like it is working with a default copy constructor?. I don't see how it is working with an object that has never been instantiated, object **v**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A(float v) { A::v = v; cout << "hola" << endl;}
    float v;
    float set(float v) {
        A::v = v;
        return v;
    }
    float get(float v) {
        return A::v;
    }
};
int main() {
    A c(2.0);
    A *v;
    A *a = new A(1.0), *b = new A(*v);
    cout << a->get(b->set(c.v));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but try not to use `v` for lots of different things it mages reading the code harder.  Some of the code is broken because of shadowing; and `A::get` just is strange.

Comment: `v` is uninitialised.  So dereferencing it (i.e. evaluating `*v`) has undefined behaviour.  But, yes, the compiler sees this as a call to the copy constructor based on the type of `*v`.   The copy constructor is implicitly generated by default.   The compiler is not required to diagnose instances of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Change `A *v;` to `A *v = nullptr;` and tell us if still "works".

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Of course reading from a null pointer is exactly as undefined as reading from an uninitialized one.  (Although it is more likely to segfault.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  We can't shed any light on how it works.  `v` has never been initialized, so trying to copy from the object it (doesn't) point at is undefined behaviour.  Trying to reason about undefined behaviour is an exercise in futility except for debugging purposes.  The most likely behaviour is either a seg-fault, or `*b` will be a copy of some random piece of memory.

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) points out in his comment the compiler is not required to diagnose instances of undefined behaviour.  In this case, I would expect most compilers to warn if you crank up the warning level (-Wall -werror are good flags to use).

Comment: It is an exercise of futility for you that may know what is going on. You can run the code a thousand times and there will never be a seg-fault, so it is far from being the most likely behaviour. Honestly, I don't see why unvote the question.

Comment: @Jules on my platform your code segfaults every time. Local variables are not initialized in C. What happens on your platform is that the uninitialized pointer `v` points by chance to some memory that your process is allowed to read, and `*v` reads whatever is in that memory location. That's why it apparently works fine on _your_ platform. _Undefined behaviour_ (google that) includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @Jules  I said the most likely behaviour is "either a seg fault or a copy of some random piece of memory", however there are a *huge* range of other possible behaviours - right up to causing your monitor to catch fire (there have certainly been computers were an errant *write* could cause that to happen; I don't think errant *reads* ever have - but it doesn't require a *particularly* outlandish design).  Given this is in main, if you don't get a seg fault the first time, you probably never will.

Comment: @Jules Incidentally, I didn't downvote your question.